# Does pandas have an 'all' or 'forever' resample specification?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[pandas.DataFrame.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) accepts a variety of [resampling specifications](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) like '1W' (weekly), 'Y' (yearly), etc.  Is there a specification for "forever" meaning to include all rows?

Obviously, one could just not call resample.  However, I have some logic where I would like resampled or non-resampled summarization to be output with the same dataframe structure.  A degenerate resampler would be most handy.

As an example, here's some data summarized by weeks:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(11), pd.date_range('2018-01-10', '2018-01-20'))
x.resample('1W').sum()

#              0
# 2018-01-14  10
# 2018-01-21  45
```

And when resampled 'forever'...

```
#              0
# 2018-01-20  55
```

...where notice there's a time-index matching `x.index.max()` and the `sum()` was taken over all rows.  I chose the maximum but the minimum could occur too. 
 It's entirely possible to munge `x.sum()` into such a format (3-4 lines)-- just seems like there may be a cuter way.

Comment: Can you give an example of a dataframe before and after `resample(forever)`?

Comment: @Tony, so added.

Comment: resample forever is nothing but apply the desired aggregate function on the entire dataframe. You can easily achieve that by using x.sum()

Comment: @Vaishali, it is the aggregate function on the entire dataframe with some additional index munging.  Using `pd.DataFrame(data=[x.sum()], index=[x.index.max()])` is the shortest I know (just cooked it up, though loses any index name).  I want a spec that behaves in this manner.

Comment: Yeah i'm not sure there's a 1 liner, by applying an aggregate function you're reducing a list of values to a single value, which has no access to the index.  I think you're on the right track with creating a new dataframe.  `df.cumsum().tail(n=1)` would work for sum, but a more universal option i don't know.

Comment: Ehh guess you can access the index, but i'm not sure how you would set it: `df.apply(lambda x: (x.index.max(), sum(x)))`